# Which index to add here?

Tags: mysql, sql

This query ends up in slow query log because join without index. Which index do I add and where? This simple query takes anywhere from 500ms to 1,2s. I guess it should easily complete within 100ms.

```
SELECT users.*, user_roles.apirequests, user_roles.downloadrequests, NOW() AS now
            FROM users
            INNER JOIN user_roles ON user_roles.id = users.role
            WHERE users.rsstoken =
            '775e155c780ed5af9119f797f814c714' LIMIT 1;
```

See query and show create tables: https://kopy.io/iCz1z

Comment: You should read about the `explain` feature MySQL offers. Check the documentation for that. It tells you exactly _how_ it tries to use existing indexes and where something is missing.

Comment: Any reason you have `COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci` on the rsstoken column?

Comment: Don't know. I did not create this table. It's an API key that column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT u.*, ur.apirequests, ur.downloadrequests, NOW() AS now
FROM users u INNER JOIN
     user_roles ur
     ON ur.id = u.role
WHERE u.rsstoken = '775e155c780ed5af9119f797f814c714';
```

The best indexes are `users(rsstoken, role)` and `user_roles(id)`.  You already have the second index, because `id` is declared as a primary key.

You can could also include `apirequests` and `downloadrequests` in the index on `user_roles`:  `user_roles(id, apirequests, downloadrequests)`.  This might be a very small optimization -- I would generally counsel against it because `id` is already the primary key and the row size is small.

Comment: How would indexes on apirequests and downloadrequests help when they're not used in a comparison?

Comment: @thebjorn . . . That makes the index a covering index for the query.  In this case, there is almost no gain because the first key is the primary key of the table.  The only advantage is that the index is smaller than the original table, so there might be a small I/O benefit.  In other situations, covering indexes can be quite beneficial.

Comment: Okay so I did: CREATE INDEX ix_rssrole ON users (rsstoken, role); but it doesn't look like the query goes any faster :-(

Don't quite understand why. Whole DB is on SSDs too.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong. In my PHP I was still using the LOWER() function of MySQL which caused it to not use the index.  Running @ 25ms now :-) Thanks.

Comment: My load dropped from 28+ back to 6 on a 16 core machine lol. Thanks for the help.